The Windows trusted the self-signed certificate but Google Chrome returned the NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error
I created a self-signed Root CA certificate, then created an IA certificate signed with Root CA, and finally created a server certificate signed with IA certificate.
These are the commands that I use:
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Create Root CA Private key...
openssl ecparam -name secp384r1 -genkey -out "SSL-Bundle/Root-CA.key"
ECHO Create Root CA Private key successfully!

ECHO Create Root CA CSR...
openssl req -new -sha256 -key "SSL-Bundle/Root-CA.key" -config "SSL-Bundle/config_root_ca.cnf" -out "SSL-Bundle/Root-CA.csr"
ECHO Create Root CA CSR successfully!

ECHO Create Root CA...
REM Install Root CA into Trusted Root Certification Authorities store and Third-Party Root Certification Authorities store
certutil -f -addstore AuthRoot "SSL-Bundle/Root-CA.crt"
ECHO Create Root CA successfully!

ECHO Create Intermediate CA Private key...
openssl ecparam -name secp384r1 -genkey -out "SSL-Bundle/Intermediate-CA.key"
ECHO Create Intermediate CA Private key successfully!

ECHO Create Intermediate CA CSR...
openssl req -new -sha256 -key "SSL-Bundle/Intermediate-CA.key" -config "SSL-Bundle/config_intermediate_ca.cnf" -out "SSL-Bundle/Intermediate-CA.csr"
ECHO Create Intermediate CA CSR successfully!

ECHO Sign Intermediate CA CSR with Root CA...
openssl ca -config "SSL-Bundle/config_intermediate_ca.cnf" -in "SSL-Bundle/Intermediate-CA.csr" -out "SSL-Bundle/Intermediate-CA.crt"
REM Install Intermediate CA into Intermediate Certification Authorities store
certutil -f -addstore CA "SSL-Bundle/Intermediate-CA.crt"
ECHO Sign Intermediate CA CSR with Root CA successfully!

ECHO Create Server Private key...
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -out "SSL-Bundle/Certificates/server.key"
ECHO Create Server Private key successfully!

ECHO Create Server CSR...
openssl req -new -sha256 -key "SSL-Bundle/Certificates/server.key" -config "SSL-Bundle/config_server_ssl.cnf" -out "SSL-Bundle/Certificates/server.csr"
ECHO Create Server CSR successfully!

ECHO Sign Server CSR with Intermediate CA...
openssl ca -config "SSL-Bundle/config_server_ssl.cnf" -in "SSL-Bundle/Certificates/server.csr" -out "SSL-Bundle/Certificates/server.crt"
ECHO Sign Server CSR with Intermediate CA successfully!

These are the configuration files that I use:
config_root_ca.cnf:
[ req ]
prompt=no
string_mask=default
distinguished_name=req_distinguished_name
default_bits=2048

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName=VN
# stateOrProvinceName=
# localityName=
organizationName=Localhost Inc.
organizationalUnitName=Localhost Co., Ltd.
commonName=Root CA ECC
# emailAddress=

# we use 'ca' as the default section because we're usign the ca command
[ ca ]
default_ca=root_ca

[ root_ca ]
# a text file containing the next serial number to use in hex. Mandatory.
# This file must be present and contain a valid serial number.
serial=SSL-Bundle/Root-CA.srl

# the text database file to use. Mandatory. This file must be present though
# initially it will be empty.
database=SSL-Bundle/Root-CA.txt

# specifies the directory where new certificates will be placed. Mandatory.
new_certs_dir=SSL-Bundle/Certificates

# the file containing the CA certificate. Mandatory
certificate=SSL-Bundle/Root-CA.crt

# the file contaning the CA private key. Mandatory
private_key=SSL-Bundle/Root-CA.key

# the message digest algorithm. Remember to not use MD5
default_md=sha384

# for how many days will the signed certificate be valid
default_days=397

# the start date to certify a certificate for
default_startdate=19700101000000Z

# either this option or default_days
default_enddate=21060207062815Z

# a section with a set of variables corresponding to DN fields
policy=root_ca_policy

# Extensions added while singing with the `openssl ca` command
x509_extensions=x509_ext

# MOST IMPORTANT PART OF THIS CONFIG
copy_extensions=copy

[ root_ca_policy ]
# if the value is "match" then the field value must match the same field in the
# CA certificate. If the value is "supplied" then it must be present.
# Optional means it may be present. Any fields not mentioned are silently
# deleted.
countryName=match
stateOrProvinceName=optional
localityName=optional
organizationName=supplied
organizationalUnitName=supplied
commonName=supplied
emailAddress=optional

[ x509_ext ]
basicConstraints=critical,CA:TRUE
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature,cRLSign,keyCertSign

config_intermediate_ca.cnf:
[ req ]
prompt=no
string_mask=default
distinguished_name=req_distinguished_name
default_bits=2048

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName=VN
# stateOrProvinceName=
# localityName=
organizationName=Localhost Inc.
organizationalUnitName=Localhost Pte. Ltd.
commonName=Intermediate CA ECC
# emailAddress=

# we use 'ca' as the default section because we're usign the ca command
[ ca ]
default_ca=intermediate_ca

[ intermediate_ca ]
# a text file containing the next serial number to use in hex. Mandatory.
# This file must be present and contain a valid serial number.
serial=SSL-Bundle/Root-CA.srl

# the text database file to use. Mandatory. This file must be present though
# initially it will be empty.
database=SSL-Bundle/Root-CA.txt

# specifies the directory where new certificates will be placed. Mandatory.
new_certs_dir=SSL-Bundle/Certificates

# the file containing the CA certificate. Mandatory
certificate=SSL-Bundle/Root-CA.crt

# the file contaning the CA private key. Mandatory
private_key=SSL-Bundle/Root-CA.key

# the message digest algorithm. Remember to not use MD5
default_md=sha384

# for how many days will the signed certificate be valid
default_days=397

# the start date to certify a certificate for
default_startdate=19700101000000Z

# either this option or default_days
default_enddate=20791231235959Z

# a section with a set of variables corresponding to DN fields
policy=intermediate_ca_policy

# Extensions added while singing with the `openssl ca` command
x509_extensions=x509_ext

# MOST IMPORTANT PART OF THIS CONFIG
copy_extensions=copy

[ intermediate_ca_policy ]
# if the value is "match" then the field value must match the same field in the
# CA certificate. If the value is "supplied" then it must be present.
# Optional means it may be present. Any fields not mentioned are silently
# deleted.
countryName=match
stateOrProvinceName=optional
localityName=optional
organizationName=supplied
organizationalUnitName=supplied
commonName=supplied
emailAddress=optional

[ x509_ext ]
basicConstraints=critical,CA:TRUE,pathlen:0
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always
keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature,keyCertSign,cRLSign
extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth,clientAuth

config_server_ssl.cnf:
[ req ]
prompt=no
string_mask=default
distinguished_name=req_distinguished_name
default_bits=2048

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName=VN
# stateOrProvinceName=
# localityName=
organizationName=Localhost Inc.
organizationalUnitName=Localhost LLC
commonName=Localhost ECC
# emailAddress=

# we use 'ca' as the default section because we're usign the ca command
[ ca ]
default_ca=server_ca

[ server_ca ]
# a text file containing the next serial number to use in hex. Mandatory.
# This file must be present and contain a valid serial number.
serial=SSL-Bundle/Intermediate-CA.srl

# the text database file to use. Mandatory. This file must be present though
# initially it will be empty.
database=SSL-Bundle/Intermediate-CA.txt

# specifies the directory where new certificates will be placed. Mandatory.
new_certs_dir=SSL-Bundle/Certificates

# the file containing the CA certificate. Mandatory
certificate=SSL-Bundle/Intermediate-CA.crt

# the file contaning the CA private key. Mandatory
private_key=SSL-Bundle/Intermediate-CA.key

# the message digest algorithm. Remember to not use MD5
default_md=sha256

# for how many days will the signed certificate be valid
default_days=397

# the start date to certify a certificate for
default_startdate=19700101000000Z

# either this option or default_days
default_enddate=20380319031407Z

# a section with a set of variables corresponding to DN fields
policy=ia_ca_policy

# Extensions added while singing with the `openssl ca` command
x509_extensions=x509_ext

# MOST IMPORTANT PART OF THIS CONFIG
copy_extensions=copy

[ ia_ca_policy ]
# if the value is "match" then the field value must match the same field in the
# CA certificate. If the value is "supplied" then it must be present.
# Optional means it may be present. Any fields not mentioned are silently
# deleted.
countryName=match
stateOrProvinceName=optional
localityName=optional
organizationName=supplied
organizationalUnitName=supplied
commonName=supplied
emailAddress=optional

[ x509_ext ]
basicConstraints=critical,CA:false
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth
subjectAltName=@alternate_names

[ alternate_names ]
DNS.1=localhost
DNS.2=*.localhost
IP.1=127.0.0.1

The Root CA certificate has been installed into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store and Third-Party Root Certification Authorities store. The IA certificate has been installed into the Intermediate Certification Authorities store. I checked through certmgr.msc, all was installed correctly, and when I opened those certificates, the Root CA, IA, and server all returned the correct certificate path and the certificate status was This certificate is OK.
When I open: Chrome Settings > Privacy and security > Security > Manage Certificates. At the Intermediate Certification Authorities tab there is a self-signed IA certificate, and at the Trusted Root Certification Authorities tab there is also a self-signed Root CA above.
Then I configured Apache:
Listen 443
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
DocumentRoot "/WWW"
    <Directory "/WWW">
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/WWW"
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias www.localhost
    <Directory "/WWW">
        Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /Apache/conf/ssl/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /Apache/conf/ssl/server.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /Apache/conf/ssl/Root-CA.crt
</VirtualHost>

But when I try to access https://localhost on Google Chrome, I still get the error NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID and at the address bar gave a red warning Not Secure.
I want to know what am I missing? How to make Google Chrome also trust my self-signed certificate (i.e. there will be no more warnings and the address bar will also change to green Secure)?
UPDATE: Below is the output of openssl x509 -noout -text -in <cert.crt> as requested by @garethTheRed.
openssl x509 -noout -text -in Root-CA.crt:
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 0 (0x0)
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
        Issuer: C = VN, O = Localhost Inc., OU = "Localhost Co., Ltd.", CN = Localhost ECC P384 Root CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan  1 00:00:00 1970 GMT
            Not After : Feb  7 06:28:15 2106 GMT
        Subject: C = VN, O = Localhost Inc., OU = "Localhost Co., Ltd.", CN = Localhost ECC P384 Root CA
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (384 bit)
                pub:
                    04:9f:a9:ed:b2:46:dd:2d:78:42:5f:cc:41:8b:6a:
                    26:82:f9:8d:5f:52:a5:ea:7c:1f:e7:73:a2:43:0c:
                    d2:69:a9:ba:b1:06:53:f8:2f:6f:94:95:59:09:4b:
                    6e:fd:51:72:54:7e:11:7a:88:cf:4b:49:99:d9:f5:
                    92:c1:19:b0:10:6f:c7:f5:e0:36:c9:5d:32:01:18:
                    d1:52:26:fb:57:d8:3c:4e:15:ba:b0:7c:80:00:bb:
                    0e:d9:bc:26:1b:1b:d5
                ASN1 OID: secp384r1
                NIST CURVE: P-384
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                74:49:7D:71:7E:A0:31:28:6E:EC:46:BA:D4:99:72:41:78:B5:11:6A
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:74:49:7D:71:7E:A0:31:28:6E:EC:46:BA:D4:99:72:41:78:B5:11:6A

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
         30:66:02:31:00:fa:2d:4a:35:4b:21:83:14:dc:13:8b:5a:e5:
         a8:da:d2:1a:86:fc:59:47:07:da:c4:2a:fd:ff:07:cc:96:4e:
         f2:d2:0d:da:80:d8:e7:e7:c6:cb:0c:b6:87:c6:f5:20:95:02:
         31:00:e2:32:d8:09:af:ef:a8:1e:03:4c:d2:e9:6f:92:bf:82:
         c7:52:8e:43:33:da:38:c9:a4:42:37:b9:cc:db:48:d9:ae:3e:
         55:43:4d:df:d5:35:f3:b0:0e:42:87:9f:b0:1a

openssl x509 -noout -text -in Intermediate-CA.crt:
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
        Issuer: C = VN, O = Localhost Inc., OU = "Localhost Co., Ltd.", CN = Localhost ECC P384 Root CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan  1 00:00:00 1970 GMT
            Not After : Dec 31 23:59:59 2079 GMT
        Subject: C = VN, O = Localhost Inc., OU = Localhost Pte. Ltd., CN = Localhost ECC P384 Intermediate CA
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (384 bit)
                pub:
                    04:07:c4:b3:2c:2f:33:cb:76:d2:19:f1:21:04:02:
                    5d:92:14:06:dc:87:c6:3d:af:c8:27:18:8d:9e:10:
                    e5:11:43:47:28:24:e5:be:b6:cf:12:8e:80:59:c8:
                    d7:82:c9:88:9b:bb:06:fa:0b:46:44:a2:39:6c:23:
                    5c:b0:a8:80:91:d9:6d:9a:4c:ae:e8:9d:69:73:b6:
                    60:81:e0:e9:69:e2:8a:44:41:dc:a3:f3:e5:ae:7e:
                    02:00:f4:41:74:22:7c
                ASN1 OID: secp384r1
                NIST CURVE: P-384
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                F3:38:E4:E6:B9:1E:EC:12:E5:80:96:00:94:A9:76:06:D1:C9:B4:89
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:74:49:7D:71:7E:A0:31:28:6E:EC:46:BA:D4:99:72:41:78:B5:11:6A
                DirName:/C=VN/O=Localhost Inc./OU=Localhost Co., Ltd./CN=Localhost ECC P384 Root CA
                serial:00

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
         30:65:02:30:68:3f:e8:2f:45:3f:fb:f9:65:62:fc:f5:3a:d0:
         b3:3e:21:9a:76:c3:b3:cc:8c:2c:77:69:48:ed:2e:85:0d:5f:
         35:8d:9b:ca:de:bb:32:d5:8b:c3:39:53:2a:c8:61:82:02:31:
         00:f2:cb:ed:ba:ba:68:19:73:f0:53:7c:10:63:3f:b8:20:4f:
         f2:19:b9:86:7b:bd:c9:b3:7d:2e:c5:34:62:e2:1f:4f:b0:24:
         9c:b3:ae:fd:f5:54:3a:08:e3:dd:f9:50:fe

openssl x509 -noout -text -in Server.crt:
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 0 (0x0)
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: C = VN, O = Localhost Inc., OU = Localhost Pte. Ltd., CN = Localhost ECC P384 Intermediate CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan  1 00:00:00 1970 GMT
            Not After : Mar 19 03:14:07 2038 GMT
        Subject: C = VN, O = Localhost Inc., OU = Localhost LLC, CN = Localhost ECC P256
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:b6:8f:91:37:73:9d:a7:31:ee:6e:d6:74:e2:15:
                    d4:af:78:cc:d5:21:1f:0a:52:be:66:af:36:01:c4:
                    d3:b1:7e:c7:99:e9:cd:0d:41:9b:e6:28:cf:26:8c:
                    f9:44:2f:c9:ee:6d:e5:f5:d3:00:82:7b:19:95:3e:
                    89:5b:ef:a2:ac
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                32:19:D3:18:FA:46:0C:A6:2B:1F:CF:A1:04:8D:99:6F:C5:03:54:AD
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:F3:38:E4:E6:B9:1E:EC:12:E5:80:96:00:94:A9:76:06:D1:C9:B4:89

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:localhost, DNS:*.localhost, IP Address:127.0.0.1
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
         30:64:02:30:4d:43:cc:3d:4e:7a:8d:78:ec:bb:01:64:60:93:
         26:96:7c:07:55:9c:66:ae:4f:13:c9:1f:d3:01:ff:ae:10:da:
         a1:ca:5b:d7:9d:f5:8f:81:89:0d:56:32:7b:53:58:ad:02:30:
         78:7e:06:56:f6:fc:93:67:ba:53:f4:cb:22:1d:15:86:62:63:
         9a:2e:fa:14:bd:8b:2c:01:a3:6b:8c:20:94:61:a9:e0:cc:a4:
         8f:c9:a8:a5:88:59:72:b1:35:5d:e2:e6


Have you tried adding the intermediate CA cert to the apache certificate?  This cert should be sent by the web server, not added to the client.  Append the intermediate CA cert to server.crt and see if that helps.  It might be better to add the output of openssl x509 -noout -text -in <cert.crt> to your question for all certs (redacted if you want).

EKU is wrong on ICA, please see this answer, as CAs/ICAs should never have EKUs. Server cert is missing KUs keyEncipherment, keyAgreement (please see aforementioned link). Also, the default_startdate year of 1970 would be invalid with default_days of 397, and SHA512 should be used over SHA256 since 64bit CPUs process SHA512 faster than SHA256. SSLCertificateChainFile in Apache should have the ICA cert containing the concatenated CA (when viewing certificate file contents, ICA cert block should be first, CA cert block should be second)

(Cont'd...) Provided the above is done, the server cert will be trusted in all browsers, as right now, even if the certs were correct (they're not), Apache is missing the ICA entirely, so the Apache server cert is essentially self-signed to a browser. If Apache allows specifying a PKCS12, you could also bundle everything into a single .p12 cert (see the (optional) Export command in Step 6 - this requires the CA be concatenated into the ICA cert, covered in Step 5: Concatenate ICA and CA Cert)

Also, encrypt_key = yes should be used within [ req ], otherwise private keys lack encryption, including the CA/ICA keys, which by default makes the entire Chain of Trust insecure. When specified, -nodes must be added to all server key creation commands to prevent the server key from being encrypted (would require manual entry of the encryption passphrase when server is started/restarted, which is impractical)

@garethTheRed The sole purpose of a CA or ICA is to sign & verify certs and maintain a CRL for revocation of certs it's issued - what use case is there for a CA/ICA to have any of the ten EKUs? I cover them in detail here - 4.2.1.12: "If a cert contains both a KU extension and an EKU extension, then both extensions MUST be processed independently and the cert MUST only be used for a purpose consistent with both extensions. If there is no purpose consistent with both extensions, then the certificate MUST NOT be used for any purpose."

(Cont'd...) @garethTheRed AFAIK, a CA/ICA will never be used for any of the EKU purposes - it will never be used for server or client authentication, will never be used to sign code or files, to encrypt emails, to add a timestamp or digital signature to a file, for OSCP signing, signing Microsoft code or files, signing commercial software, signing Trust Lists, or signing of encrypted file systems.

@JW0914 I have updated my question again, I was a bit confused with the configuration file of Root CA and ICA when posting the question. To be exact, with Root CA and ICA, default_md will be SHA384. SHA256 is only used with server certificates. Additionally, default_days will only be used if I do not specify default_enddate. But because I specified default_enddate, the certificate's expiration date is the date specified at default_enddate instead of 397 days from default_startdate.

@garethTheRed I've added the output of the CA, IA and server certificates you requested.

@garethTheRed I also tried appending the IA certificate above the -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- of Server.crt, of course the Apache server couldn't start because the Server.key didn't match. Then I appended the IA certificate above -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- of Root-CA.crt, now the Apache server started normally but the error NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID still happens.

@TầnQuảng each hierarchical cert goes below the one it issued, not above, and it can't just be the ICA, would have to be the ICA and CA (e.g. Cert, then ICA, then CA), however the concatenated ICA and CA cert (e g. ICA then CA) would still need to be specified unless using a PCKS12 cert. OpenSSL config files are way too complicated in generic form, instead try this custom one, which is covered in this answer. Use SHA512, as it's processed faster

Does this answer your question? How should I generate a self signed SSL for an intranet server, following these specific requisites?

@JW0914 No. That is not the answer!

Okay, I've identified the problem and found a solution. The command line and configuration file I used generated the certificates in question without any problem. The error was determined to be due to a feature called Chrome Root Store and Certificate Verifier. This feature was added since Chrome 105:

We expect the transition to the Chrome Root Store and Chrome Certificate Verifier to be seamless for most users.
As the transition occurs, a small population of users may notice that a small number of websites that successfully loaded in earlier versions of Chrome now present a “Your connection is not private” warning. When a website’s certificate does not validate to a certificate included in the Chrome Root Store or a user’s local settings, users will see detailed error language that includes “ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.”

Although also according to this article, a certificate added to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store will also be trusted by Chrome Certificate Verifier, but since it is not in the Chrome Root Store it will give the same warning as the certificate not trusted.
I tried on older versions (Chrome 49 - Chrome Root Store and Certificate Verifier feature is not available, uses platform root store and verifier) these certificates work fine:
And according to the article Testing the Chrome Root Store and Certificate Verifier, the only workaround is to disable Chrome Root Store and Certificate Verifier. Here is how to do it (on Chrome >= 105):

Disable the Chrome Root Store & Certificate Verifier by starting Chrome with the following flag: --disable-features=ChromeRootStoreUsed

Disable the Chrome Root Store and Certificate Verifier by going to chrome://flags, searching for the flag Chrome Root Store (chrome://flags/#chrome-root-store-enabled), and set it to Disabled. This will then require Chrome to restart.


And here is the result (I tested on Chrome 109):

Note: The Root Store and Certificate Verifier feature is available on all browsers using Chromium, including Microsoft Edge. This feature is called Microsoft Root Store on Microsoft Edge.

There might be a better path. Why is this the case "At the Intermediate Certification Authorities tab there is a self-signed IA certificate"...  either you installed it in Chrome or it your ssl server gave it to Chrome, both are wrong. The self-signed cert in the cert store of Chrome may lead it to build a chain from the server cert to the intermedia certificate and so fail to chain to a certificate in the trusted root store. Consider removing that certificate from Chrome and either configuring the server better, or (worse) putting the intermediate cert in the trusted root store.

This doesn't resolve your ICA and server certs being malformed - ICA shouldn't have any EKUs and server cert needs KUs keyEncipherment, keyAgreement. Since those certs are still malformed, that is the issue, not what this answer covers. Instead of looking for a workaround to make malformed certs work, simply regenerate the ICA without EKUs and the server cert with the correct KUs - takes all of a few minutes to do. How is the malformed server cert supposed to negotiate key exchange w/o the requisite KUs?

@Ram I tested the settings as in my answer which helped both Chrome and Windows Certificate Viewer build the correct certificate path: Root CA -> ICA -> server. I even tried installing both Root CA and ICA into the Windows Trusted Root Certification Authorities store, but Chrome ignored ICA and only kept the Root CA as available in Chrome's Trusted Root Certification Authorities. But all that doesn't matter if you use Chromium browser >= 105 because it will only trust certificates present in their own Root Store and will ignore certificates present on Windows (as in my answer).

@JW0914 I think whether the (self-signed) certificate contains KUs and EKUs or not does not affect it because the configuration files in question are also referenced from many sources, including the answer you gave, and of course, whether they contain KUs and EKUs or not, the Chromium browser >=105 still gives the NET:: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID warning. I then edited the configuration file by referring to the applicable Root CA and ICA certificates to complete in the configuration files above.

@JW0914  But if your solution works, I hope you'll write it down in an answer, giving the correct configuration files and proof image it worked on Chromium >=105 (at least with Google Chrome), which will not only help me but will also help people with the same situation later. I would appreciate that!

@TầnQuảng your problem, as has been stated numerous times, is your certs are malformed and have not been correctly created. I've linked to the answer several times between your question and your answer - please take the time to read through pages that are linked to. To correctly generate the certs, please follow Steps 1 - 6

@JW0914 I'm wondering if you've tried running those command lines on Windows? I tried up to step 4 but from step 3 there was an error (most of the time it will be a file not found error), especially Windows only uses " when you use ' in the file name, it will generate a file of the form 'file_name' and cause the file not found error (in step 3). Step 4 will continue to get an error in the Convert CA CRL Cert to DER CRL command. I find it exhausting to find out the cause and find a way to fix those errors.

@JW0914 I hope you can write it into an answer, provide some photos/videos that prove that the solution in your answer works, or at least provide the certificate files that you created from those command lines so that I can test and come up with results that it works on Chromium 105 or higher.
At least for now, I still believe according to Chromium's official documentation and solution, the result I got (as in my answer) rather than a "your certs are malformed and have not been correctly created" conclusion without proof.

??? The proof your certs are malformed is the certs you posted in your question, and I stated exactly what was malformed in a comment under your question. I also linked to another answer listing every KU and EKU, along with the definition for each. Might I suggest reading through the links that have been posted, which provide everything you've asked to be shown. I digress to my prior comments and will not be commenting further. This answer has been downvoted because it's not the cause, and instead of correctly reissuing the certs, instead days have been spent to get malformed certs to work?

@JW0914 As far as I understand it, what you mean by that is because I created the certificate "are malformed and have not been correctly" so the browser gave me the warning NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID rather than the Root Store feature. And if I create the certificate following the steps in the answer you provided, this error will no longer appear.

So, I hope you can provide an answer that you created the certificate in the right format and exactly according to that answer, and when testing on the Chromium browser >= 105 + without disabling the Root Store feature, it should work normally as on older browser versions.

While I don't know who downvoted my answer, I don't care because it answered the heart of the question I was asking anyway: The self-signed certificate I created didn't have a problem, it was caused by the Root Store feature, and the only solution was to disable it (or use an older version browser, although this is not recommended).
